# Can I define new mustache template variables in swagger-codegen?

Tags: swagger, mustache, swagger-codegen, template-variables

I have developed a rest-api client (in java) customised to the needs of my product.  I wanted to generate tests using my rest api client  using swagger-codegen modules based on yaml-file.

I have already extended `DefaultCodegenConfig` & even tried implementing the `CodegenConfig` interface to build my custom jar. I have customized the `api.mustache` and `api_test.mustache` files and passing them in the `constructor` and `processOpts()` method of my `CustomCodeGen` that extends `DefaultCodegenConfig`.

However, I want to use the custom/new mustache template variables that I have added in my customised `api.mustache`.

For e.g. if refer to standard [api.mustache](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen-generators/blob/master/src/main/resources/handlebars/Java/api.mustache), the template variables it typically uses are

```
 - {{classname}} 
 - {{#operation}} 
 - {{#contents}} 
 - {{#parameters}}
```

etc.

Now, I want to introduce a new template variable, let's say `{{custom_param}}`. Now I am not clear how do I integrate this new template variable with the implementation.

Looks like from this [Mustache-Template-Variables](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/wiki/Mustache-Template-Variables) published here, swagger-codegen does not allow adding new template-variables and perhaps we are restricted to only the variables mentioned on this page.

So, is there some way to make the new template variables work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time ago I added the `uniqueItems` parameter for bean validation as it was not getting processed by the engine even though it was a part of the implemented JSR.

So I believe codebase needs to be updated to use your own variable which is only possible if you fork the code.

In case it helps, these two were the PRs:

1. For query parameters: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/pull/10154.
2. For body parameters: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/pull/10490.

Comment: Yes, such customisations are not feasible with source-code changes.